# Blender doesn't recognize Cython created module

Tags: python, scripting, import

I'm trying to speed up some erosion simulations (simulating 10's of thousands of raindrops) I have in python but I cannot get Blender to even import a cython created module. I've created a super simple example in hopes of figuring it out but haven't yet. Any Cython advice is welcome! I'm working with the 2.83 LTS version, using/compiling with python version 3.7.4, and I am using *easycython* to build my cython files.

I tried [Dr. Sybren's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110071/import-custom-module-not-working-pyd-file) but to no avail -
Here's the python code:

```
bl_info = {
"name": "Test",
"description": "",
"author": "Zach Eastin",
"version": (0, 5, 1),
"blender": (2, 83, 0),
"location": "View 3D > Properties Panel",
"support": "COMMUNITY",
"category": "Mesh"
}

import bpy
from os.path import dirname,join
import sys
fpath = join( dirname(__file__),"simple.pyd" )
if fpath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(fpath)
# import simple
from . simple import f

class MyClassName(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my_operator.my_class_name"
    bl_label = "My Class Name"
    bl_description = "Description that shows in blender tooltips"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    def execute(self, context):
        # print("Cy:",simple.f(3,4))

        print("Cy:", f(3, 4))
        return {"FINISHED"}


class PanelClassName(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "panelname"
    bl_label = "Panelname"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("my_operator.my_class_name")

clss = [
    MyClassName,
    PanelClassName
]

def register():
    for cls in clss :
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in clss :
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

And then my Cython code

```
def f(int x, int y):
    return x*y
```

Really any help would be sooo appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've also tried adding `fpath = join( dirname(__file__) )` instead of the actual pyd file and still nothing

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? I think the space in `. simple` in your import statement is invalid syntax. What platform are you running this on?

Comment: I just went to writing pure C and importing it into python as a module. If I remember correctly it worked if I ran it outside of Blender but once in Blender it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

you should have it in dll searches by means of environment variabl
try `os.environ['PATH'] += your_dll_directory`
or use `os.add_dll_directory(path)` for your C files. *(whichever works - in my case the first one works)*

or You can add the path manually to EnvironmentVariables PATH (if it contains dlls) and also add it to PYTHONPATH.

blender may crash in other cases.